# Converting string to date returning null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to convert a string in my SQL database into a date so I can order by that date.

'16 Jul 2016' is an example of the date format and i am using the following code to convert it but my output is NULL.

```
STR_TO_DATE(  `DATE` ,  '%DD %Mon %YYYY' ) AS thedatething
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct format string:

```
str_to_date(date, '%d %b %Y')
```

You seem to have a strange mix of Oracle and MySQL formats in your string.  The MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is quite clear.

Comment: still giving me null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(col, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM table
```